# /rest/V1/products filtering by price and special price

Tags: rest-api

I am using the Rest API to query for products. When I set the order by to "price" it orders everything properly while also taking into account currently active special prices.

My issue is that when I try filtering by "price" it ignores special price. I was thinking I could add another filter group for special price but then it takes into account all specials even if they are no longer active.

Is there any way to filter by price while also taking into account current special prices?

Here is my search url:

```
/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=0.25&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=0.88&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=lteq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=price&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Less Than of Equal to" "0.888" is not fetching any results.
What its doing is trying to get products between 0.25 and 0.888 $.
Increase the 0.888 value to say 100 or 1000 and you will get results.
I did and it works for me.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In order to include both **regular** and **discounted** products in your filter query - do logical AND & OR search like so:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]:price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]:MIN_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]:gteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]:special_price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]:MIN_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]:gteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]:price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]:MAX_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]:lteq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]:special_price
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]:MAX_PRICE
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]:lteq
```

Check out this link if you need more search query examples - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html#logical-and-search